# What's the best way to upload massive (20 - 30 gig) files from a client to a server?

Tags: file-upload

This is the third edit to the question, and I've now removed the original text as it's clearly no longer relevant.

I need to write a client that will allow users to upload massive files to the server.  AJAX and Flash appear to be out as they insist on reading the files into memory before submitting them.  I've been looking around at pre-built applets but nothing looks entirely promising.

Looking for advice on how to do this.  The issue is both client and server side.  PHP is probably not the best server side solution for gathering such files... for that matter does the server need to be 64bit to even address a file that's over 4gigs?

On the client, I'd prefer it be browser based, but am now thinking that maybe it's better to write it as a platform application (even though that's a lot more hassle).

Really, I'm open to anything, as long as it's relatively reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of Flash uploaders already created that may already support your need or help you to get started, that are easy enough to Google. That said, for a multi-GB file uploader, you might want to consider designing an uploader that uploads large files in chunks obviously, and allows recovery in the event of a network disconnection...it would be terrible if I uploaded 1.9GB and then lost my connection with .1GB remaining to upload! In addition, on your PHP side, you would only be receiving much smaller chunks that might be easier to manage memory-wise. You could then combine all chunks together on the PHP side once all were received.

The Flash client side and the server side would need to interoperate with this kind of design. I.e. the server needs to understand your custom chunking protocol. You might want to consider client bandwidth saving approaches such as compressing the chunks that the Flash client then uploads, and then uncompressing those chunks on the server.

You might want to consider Flash local storage in order to make a robust "pause/continue" user process. For example, I upload 1/2 GB of a 2GB file, then my power goes out. It would be great for me to go back to the upload page, and have the Flash resume where I left off. Flash local storage might be the way to go to support that, http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help02.html. You could use the local storage to track the user's local file path that they were uploading, and the chunk that was last successfully uploaded, for example.

If this is to be deployed in a secure environment, you may need to support authentication in your Flash client...depending on where you plan to deploy this.

Don't know if that helps at all for Flash ideas, just thought I'd chime in.

I don't know well a pure AJAX approach would work for multi-GB upload scenarios.

Comment: Just a small remark, we dropped flash because the upload options we tested at the time (1 year ago) did not have support for ISA Proxies, since we work with mostly Microsoft networks we moved to Silverlight for the problem is non-existant but the smaller interop.

Comment: Was that via the RTMP protocol in Flash? ISA server should support any protocol / port. There may have been a firewall config change that could have been done within it to allow the Flash protocol, if the Flash was not communicating over standard HTTP(s). Did the Silverlight solution use the same protocol / port as the Flash solution did?

Comment: thanks shan.  I'm upvoting your answer, but will leave it open for some alternatives.  I definitely don't want to break the file up into parts for this. I'd rather just use Java and upload the file as one thing.  this applet http://www.radinks.com/upload/ appears to do that. I'll report back on what I find.

Comment: Looks like a viable solution. It support resume as well, http://www.radinks.com/upload/plus/resume.php. If resume is forced with it, it will require you to support chunked uploads, on the server side...which I'd probably do, since I'd hate a 2GB file to crap out. But I defer to your knowledge of your file uploading audience and their bandwidth throughput / stability.

Comment: yeah, well... it looks like they're either a sham corporation or out of business. They have not replied to my queries and their order form doesn't work (nor their phone number).

Comment: Could be a one-man team who created the product, perhaps. If you're able to get a source code license and are willing to get hands on, it might not be an issue if it works for most of your scenarios. But yeah, if you're looking to buy and not customize the source, your best bet may be to go with a product that has an active community and some positive reviews.

Comment: it sounds like you used flash for this in the past, but my impression is that the first thing that happens when you select a file via their file browser mechanism is that it reads it into memory.  Am I missing something? Is there a Flash way to get a file handle in the traditional sense that is simply a pointer to the disk and not an actual HEAP variable?

Comment: I've integrated multi-platform uploaders (flash, ajax), but never run into the huge files issue. Perhaps like you're discovering, some Flash is limited to whatever browser security restrictions might exist. You can't use the Adobe Air File APIs since you're looking in-browser. So you're limited to however the Flash implementation streams files, and there doesn't appear to be any control in the Flash APIs to determine how file memory buffering would occur. You might be better off looking into launching a non-browser app that's based on say Adobe Air or Silverlight, or Java, etc.

Comment: Those other options would give you other File APIs that would allow you to open files and just read whatever portions of the files you wished to.

Comment: I've integrated uploaders using chunked approaches as well, although the files sizes were a lot smaller

Comment: AIR is definitely an option! What AS3 class do you use for reading through files without loading them into memory (the idea being to read through the file, creating slices as I go, and then uploading those slices one at a time and reassembling on the server).

Comment: Try:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html. I.e. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#readBytes()

Comment: Ah... so, fileStream acts like a normal read() function? That looks like it's the case... I think this will do! thanks. You should modify your answer to include the AIR suggestion, so that if someone finds this post, they won't have to read through all our inane commentary to find the solution! :)

Comment: It allows you to read an arbitrary number of bytes. Do the chunking thing on the client side though, you wouldn't want to allocate a 2GB+ memory buffer in Air, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Hmm... well, I seem to have hit a wall here.  Unless I'm missing something byteStream does appear to want to load the entire file into memory. The async version of the open method allows you to start working with the data as soon as it starts loading, but that doesn't change the fact that it IS loading it into memory and you can't seem to play with any part of the file that hasn't been loaded yet.  Maybe I'm missing something, but this seems like a non-starter.   http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#event:progress

Comment: Re the ProgressEvent - when is that event called? Are you using that in the context of a FileReference (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html)? If so, I can imagine that that would still cause the issue. What I meant in using the FileStream API is, bypass using the FileReference API altogether...i.e. roll your own "user selects a file on file system", then use the FileStream to open the file and read the contents of it, using a buffered approach. Air supports random IO. Read to a ByteArray, then call your webservice....

Comment: ...each time you populate your ByteArray. I.e. that would bypass the FileReference altogether. See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7dc4.html for example. Is that possible to do?

Comment: Shan, I wish these comments allowed for code samples, but yes, I have abandoned the FileReference and am passing a regular File to the fileStream object. You need that to open it.  I was actually thinking the same thing... if only I can skip the "open" part of it and get it to know what file I'm interested in looking at and then just call the readBytes() method (which lets you take whatever slice you want from any position) that would work, but I don't see a way to avoid passing a File to fileStream to open it, and without that, I think I'm dead in the water.

Comment: FileStream has a readAhead property, http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#readAhead. It is applicable to asynchronous reads (that's how you probably should be reading your files in your scenario). By default it is set to infinity, meaning that for async reads, by default Air creates a memory buffer as large as the file. If you set this to something smaller and more manageable for your chunks, say 16384, then you should be able to manage the memory allocation process on your own. Note this from the API help (see next comment):

Comment: From API help at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#readAhead: Reading data from the read buffer does not change the value of the readAhead property. When you read data from the buffer, new data is read in to refill the read buffer.

Comment: indeed. readAhead solves everything and allows me to read through any size file. I think the documentation is less than stellar, but I guess that's neither here nor there. readAhead is the key to the whole thing. Thanks again.

Comment: The Air API design is also not consistent with other language I/O APIs